# 5k .. 10k reputation bug? header shows (unavailable) own suggested edit

Tags: support, bug, design, reputation

I have a really minor question. Now that I'm (just) over 5k in reputation, I have the [approve tag wiki edits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege (which I haven't had a chance to use yet), but I think it's causing my Unix.SE header to show my own pending edits. I just submitted a tag edit, and back on the main screen, I see:

[image: 5k suggested edit header]

If I click on the `2` next to the review link, it takes me to https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits where it says

> This queue has been cleared!

(Yet I know that my edits are still pending). The *actual* suggested edits queue (for Q & A edits) actually *is* clear (at the moment). I'm assuming this link has used different logic from the UI header to come to the correct conclusion that I can't approve my own edits.

So, is it a simple UI bug, or is it something harder to fix? Or do I just ignore this until I get to 10k :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers shown there are the absolute number of pending review items. This includes things you've already cast a vote on and those you've submitted yourself. The SE devs have [explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/203101) on the main meta that having the numbers be per-user is too costly and have chosen to cache it instead:

> Correct, @gnat: this is everything in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't review. Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply not having an indicator. Think of it as... A reminder to encourage your peers to review.- Shog9  [Apr 29 '14 at 22:29](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#comment758002_230726)

Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251914/203101.

Comment: There should be a meta tag, "yet another thing that's been exhaustively discussed on SE that I am unaware of" -- learning something every day; thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller - this used to drive me crazy too but I've learned to just live with it 8-). Congrats on the 5k leveling up!